Why does an upcast object call a method of a subclass that overrides a method of the superclass?
In the process of learning Java, I know that an upcast object will call a method of a subclass that overrides a method of the superclass. For example, JLS 8.4.8.1:

Example 8.4.8.1-1. Overriding
class Point { 
 int x = 0, y = 0; 
 void move(int dx, int dy) { x += dx; y += dy; } 
} 
class SlowPoint extends Point { 
 int xLimit, yLimit; 
 void move(int dx, int dy) { 
 super.move(limit(dx, xLimit), limit(dy, yLimit)); 
 } 
 static int limit(int d, int limit) {
 return d > limit ? limit : d < -limit ? -limit : d; 
 } 
}

Here, the class SlowPoint overrides the declarations of method move of
class Point with its own move method, which limits the distance that
the point can move on each invocation of the method. When the move
method is invoked for an instance of class SlowPoint, the overriding
definition in class SlowPoint will always be called, even if the
reference to the SlowPoint object is taken from a variable whose type
is Point.

Today, I tried to find relevant specifications in the JLS. I found some relevant paragraphs, but it made me confused:
JLS  15.12.1:

For the type to search, there are six cases to consider, depending on
the form that precedes the left parenthesis of the MethodInvocation:
...
• If the form is ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier, then the
type to search is the declared type T of the variable denoted by
ExpressionName if T is a class or interface type, or the upper bound
of T if T is a type variable.

According to this rule, if there is Superclass superclass = new Subclass();
Then for superclass.Identifier();,
superclass is resolved as an ExpressionName. But the declared type of superclass is Superclass rather than Subclass. So the method call should search in the superclass rather than the subclass. Isn't this a contradiction?
I suspect that I have missed something or understood something wrong, so I am seeking help here.

posted subsection describes a "Compile-Time Step", as stated in its title, but there is also 15.12.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation, more specifically 15.12.4.4. Locate Method to Invoke: "overriding may occur. A dynamic method lookup, specified below, is used to locate the method to invoke. The lookup procedure starts from class R, the actual run-time class of the target object. ..."

(( I assumed the real question is "where/how is that specified" and not really  "Why does ..." since it is one of the important features of overriding ))

You missed the dynamic dispatch point. See for example "15.12.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation" and specifically "15.12.4.4. Locate Method to Invoke" in JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4

The declared type of a variable only specifies which methods it can find (that is, it cannot find methods only defined in the subclass if T is the superclass). However, at runtime, when you invoke a method defined in a superclass, it will invoke the lowest override it can find (down to the actual type of the object), so if the subclass (or an intermediate subclass) overrides the method, that overridden method is invoked. That is how runtime polymorphism works, and if it worked in any way else, object-oriented programming would not work.

@Mark Rotteveel Embarrassingly, as a beginner, I don't understand why, since there are rules for determining which method to call at runtime, there are still rules for method search at compile time.

The declared type determines which method signatures are available, and at runtime, the right implementation of that signature is selected based on the actual type of the referenced object. That is so you get a compile time error trying to call a method that is not actually defined by the declared type, but for correct object-oriented polymorphistic behaviour, it has to dispatch to the lowest overridden method (otherwise you can't have different behaviour for different subclasses of an object, and think about what would happen if the declared type is an interface or abstract class!).
